# How to remove the local storage of a link colour when user closes the web page

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I know similar questions have been asked before, but that solutions clears the local storage on page refresh.
i have a local storage to show which link is currently active so that the user knows which menu option was last pressed eventhough the page is refreshed.

```
  
  /*===== LINK ACTIVE  =====     keeps the colour in the clicked link even after refresh*/
  const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')
  
  function colorLink() {
    linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove('active'))
    this.classList.add('active')
    
    // Added this to read data attribute
    let this_index = this.getAttribute("data-nav_link_index")
    localStorage.setItem("active_nav_link", this_index)
  }
  linkColor.forEach((l,i) => {
    l.addEventListener('click', colorLink);
    
    // Added this to set data attribute
    l.setAttribute("data-nav_link_index", i);
    
    // Added this to add the active class
    if(localStorage.getItem("active_nav_link")==i){
      l.classList.add("active");
    }else if(localStorage.getItem("active_nav_link")!==null){
      l.classList.remove("active");
    }
  })
```

Now when i login to the main Dashboard page the colour remains in the last clicked menu . Is there a way i can clear this colour on exiting the page so the user sees no colour on login. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `localStorage.removeItem("active_nav_link")` on login

Comment: Perfect !! i added this on my login page and it works so well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use session storage instead of local storage.

Session storage is cleared when the tab or browser is closed.

Answer (score 0):

- If you wants to clear items from localStorage just use `localStorage.removeItem('item')` and if you wants to clear all items just use `localStorage.clear()` and if you wants to remove that item when the user leave the page use `window.onunload` event